How can we get $\frac{\partial^2 u}{ \partial \nu\partial y_i}=0$
Let $\Omega$ is bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$, $u \in C^2(\bar{\Omega})$, $u > 0$ in $\Omega$, $u = 0$ in $\partial\Omega$, if $\exists x_0 \in \partial \Omega$ s.t. $\nabla u(x_0)=0$. $\nu$ is the exterior unit normal of $\partial \Omega$ at $x_0$, and then we can bulid a coordinate at $x_0$, by selecting $n-1$ mutually perpendicular unit vectors(such as $y_1, y_2,\cdots, y_{n-1} \in T_{x_0}\partial \Omega$) on the tangent plane and $\nu$, How can we get
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{ \partial\nu\partial y_i} = 0.
$$
Here are some things that might be useful：
For the point $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$ and any smooth curve $\left(x_1(t), \ldots, x_d(t)\right) \in \partial \Omega$, which passes through $x_0$ at $t=0$, we have
$$
u\left(x_1(t), \ldots, x_n(t)\right) \equiv 0
$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $t$ and evaluating at $t=0$, we obtain
$$
\begin{gathered}
D u\left(x_1(t), x_2(t), \cdots, x_n(t)\right) \cdot\left(\dot{x_1}(t), \dot{x_2}(t), \ldots, \dot{x_n}(t)\right)=0 \\
D u\left(x_1(0), x_2(0), \cdots, x_n(0)\right) \cdot\left(\dot{x_1}(0), \dot{x_2}(0), \ldots, \dot{x_n}(0)\right)=0
\end{gathered}
$$
By the arbitrariness of the curve, we can get $\nabla(x) = -a(x) \nu(x), \forall x \in \partial \Omega$.Use $u > 0$ in $\Omega$, $u = 0$ in $\partial\Omega$, we can get  $a(x) \geq 0$
